# Insert Procedure showing compilation error (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle 12c and a certain requirement needs me to prepare an insert procedure. I am not very familiar with procedures so would you please tell me what's wrong?

Table statement:

```
create table sa_d_pmnt(
  a_id number,
  d_n_id number,
  b_id number,
  b_b_id number,
  p_a number,
  r_n varchar2(255),
  dt date
  );
```

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure setdepositpayment (
  a_id sa_d_pmnt.a_id%TYPE,
  d_n_id sa_d_pmnt.d_n_id%TYPE,
  b_id sa_d_pmnt.b_id%TYPE,
  b_b_id sa_d_pmnt.b_b_id%TYPE,
  p_a sa_d_pmnt.p_a%TYPE,
  r_n sa_d_pmnt.r_n%TYPE,
  dt sa_d_pmnt.dt%TYPE)
is
begin
  insert into sa_d_pmnt (
    a_id,
    d_n_id,
    b_id,
    b_b_id,
    p_a,
    r_n,
    dt
  )
  values
    (
      a_id,
      d_n_id,
      b_id,
      b_b_id,
      p_a,
      r_n,
      dt
    );
  commit;
end;
/
```

I am getting **ora-00900 invalid sql statement** and **ora-24344 success with compilation error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to set parameters' names differently than column names; that causes problems. For example, use `par_` prefix.

Though, even if you don't do that in **this** case (as you're only inserting values), nothing would happen.

Procedure looks OK and executes correctly with or without prefix.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure setdepositpayment (
  2    par_a_id sa_d_pmnt.a_id%TYPE,
  3    par_d_n_id sa_d_pmnt.d_n_id%TYPE,
  4    par_b_id sa_d_pmnt.b_id%TYPE,
  5    par_b_b_id sa_d_pmnt.b_b_id%TYPE,
  6    par_p_a sa_d_pmnt.p_a%TYPE,
  7    par_r_n sa_d_pmnt.r_n%TYPE,
  8    par_dt sa_d_pmnt.dt%TYPE)
  9  is
 10  begin
 11    insert into sa_d_pmnt (
 12      a_id,
 13      d_n_id,
 14      b_id,
 15      b_b_id,
 16      p_a,
 17      r_n,
 18      dt
 19    )
 20    values
 21      (
 22        par_a_id,
 23        par_d_n_id,
 24        par_b_id,
 25        par_b_b_id,
 26        par_p_a,
 27        par_r_n,
 28        par_dt
 29      );
 30    commit;
 31  end;
 32  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec setdepositpayment(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'A', sysdate);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from sa_d_pmnt;

      A_ID     D_N_ID       B_ID     B_B_ID        P_A R_N   DT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- -------------------
         1          1          1          1          1 A     24.01.2022 11:22:01

SQL>
```

---

As of compilation errors: if you're using SQL*Plus, type `show err` and Oracle will let you know what's wrong. For example, I removed comma:

```
<snip>
 23        d_n_id,
 24        b_id,
 25        b_b_id,
 26        p_a,
 27        r_n        --> removed comma
 28        dt
 29      );
 30    commit;
 31  end;
 32  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE SETDEPOSITPAYMENT:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
28/7     PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
SQL>
```

Or, query `USER_ERRORS`:

```
SQL> select line, position, text
  2  from user_errors
  3  where name = 'SETDEPOSITPAYMENT';

      LINE   POSITION TEXT
---------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------
        28          7 PL/SQL: ORA-00917: missing comma
        11          3 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

SQL>
```

Comment: It was just an example which shows that - when there's something "wrong" with the procedure - Oracle will raise compilation error. That's why I got some output while querying USER_ERORRS because - if there were no errors - I wouldn't be able to illustrate what kind output you can expect.